# PHP Forwarding Form Action/Having Multiple Actions On A Form

Tags: php, forms

At the moment I have code that submits a form and deals with it internally on the same page... which I wish to keep. but I would like to get a copy of that form on another Page.php without having the user to submit the form twice... I realise there are multiple ways around communicating the information i.e via sessions but is there anyway to directly forward a form to another page... or send it to two pages/have two actions

Current form:

```
<form action="" method="post" style="">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Login or Register</legend>
Username<br><input type="text" name="username" /><br>
Password<br><input type="Password" name="password" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="log in" name="login"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to check if the post was submitted,  and if so, include another php file that deals with it as well. So you only have 1 action, but you process it twice,  which by the way is weird, you should take a close look as to why you would need to process information on two different pages when they originate from one.